# Minitest: Integration test, Template pattern and NotImplementedError

Tags: ruby, integration-testing, minitest

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class AbstractClass
  # code omitted

  def get_from_api(data)
    APIRequestClass.send_request(config_info: config_info(data))
  end

  # force subclass to add method w/ proper config hash
  def config_info(data)
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

I want to write an integration test that submits a request to the API. However, I need to define `config_info` to do this. Here is one of my attempts at making this work:

```
# abstract_class_test.rb
# once this works I would remove class declaration to helper file
require_relative '../test_setup'

class SpecificClass < AbstractClass
  def config_info(data)
    {
      sample: "Foo",
      data:   data
    }
  end
end


class AbstractClassTests < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    @instance = SpecificClass.new
  end

  def test_that_something_comes_back_from_api
    puts @instance.config_info("data")
    response = @instance.get_from_api("data")

    assert_equal jobs.class, Array
  end

end
```

The `puts` statement is resulting in a `NotImplementedError`.

- Is there a better way to write an integration test in this instance (i.e. not defining a `SpecificClass`)?
- Why isn't `SpecificClass`' implementation of `config_info` in the method lookup path?
- Is there a better way to force the end user to provide the configuration information needed to make the API request?

For now I'll simply test the `APIRequestClass.send_request` method and pass in the appropriate hash. I'm still very interested in the questions I asked above, but perhaps a fourth question is:  is there a significant advantage in testing this functionality all the way from `AbstractClass`, versus simply testing it from `APIRequestClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a significant advantage in testing this functionality all the way from AbstractClass, versus simply testing it from APIRequestClass?

It looks the only thing being tested is the abstract class's unimplemented method, so maybe not?  From a certain perspective, the abstract class is an implementation detail of the specific classes, so maybe it makes more sense to test the specific classes instead.

> is there a better way to force the end user to provide the configuration information needed to make the API request?

It seems like the configuration and data could be two separate, required params to `send_request` that are combined inside the method.  That might get you out of having an abstract class altogether.

> is there a better way to write an integration test in this instance (i.e. not defining a SpecificClass)

Following from the above, you could test that the configuration and data are properly combined into an API payload on the `APIRequestClass`.  There may or may not be anything left to test on the specific class at that point.

Comment: I need the abstract class as it is an abstraction that will be used across numerous implementations, each of which have their own permutations on `config_info`.  And yes, I think testing the `APIRequestClass` makes the most sense. Thanks.